# Interior Point Solver with Krylov Newton System Solver

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

Are there any open source IPM solvers that allow for different specifying the Newton solver? Specifically, when making Newton steps using the relaxed complementarity condition, can I specify that the solver use MINRES on the Newton system? What technique do most solvers currently use to solve the Newton system (which should look something like [eq. 7](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~gondzio/reports/ipmXXV.pdf))?

Comment: Most commonly a reduced version of (7) (reduced to a symmetric and positive definite system of $m$ equations in the $m$ unknowns $y$) is solved by Cholesky factorization.  As the algorithm approaches an optimal solution, this system of equations becomes very poorly conditioned, making iterative methods a poor choice.

Comment: Maybe not MINRES specifically, but you want to be looking for "matrix-free interior-point methods", with Jacek Gondzio as the number one academic in that space.

Comment: Great, thanks! I hadn't head of the term/field matrix-free IPMs and will start there.

Comment: Well, you were already close, given your cited article!

Comment: Gondzio's HOPDM code has been extended to include a matrix-free solver, but I don't believe this is included in the older version that has been released to the public.  Although it has been used to solve huge problems, I haven't seen any claim that outperforms codes based on direct factorization of the reduced KKT system for problems of more normal size.